# TSQL OR inside CASE statement's THEN section

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

I need to use an OR statement inside a CASE statement's THEN Section... Something like this.

```
DECLARE @myColorPreference varchar(10)
SET @myColorPreference = 'ANY'

SELECT BikeColor, Make, Model
FROM BIKES
WHERE Color = CASE
                WHEN @myColorPreference = 'Blue' THEN 'Blue'
                WHEN @myColorPreference = 'ANY' THEN 'Blue' OR 'Red' OR 'Green'
          END
```

Comment: The THEN part of CASE can't be multi-valued.

Comment: @MitchWheat Then can you please tell me how I should refactor this to make it work?

Comment: No, because it is unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the ANY preference means *any* colour and you want to match any other colour preference to the colour specified, the simplest solution to this would be:

```
SELECT BikeColor, Make, Model
FROM BIKES
WHERE @myColorPreference in (Color,'ANY')
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
SELECT BikeColor, Make, Model
FROM BIKES
WHERE Color = @myColorPreference OR
     @myColorPreference = 'ANY'
```

People frequently overcomplicate their SQL and try to make it fit an existing pattern from an imperative language, when in fact they need to work out a simpler `WHERE` clause that says what they want.

Comment: @Kulingar - well, whatever the `WHEN @myColorPreference = 'ANY'` part of your *question* was, that's what's currently the second part of my `WHERE` clause is. But certainly, if you've "abstracted" your question such that the posted answers don't make sense, then you've not done a good job of abstracting your question and/or you need to make your question more concrete.

Comment: @Kulingar - are you sure you've read the answers correctly - I'm testing for two possibilities in the `where` clause - either the `Color` column matches the `@myColorPreference` variable (whatever value it may be set to), or, in the alternative, if the `@myColorPreference` variable is equal to `Any`, then we want this row (and it doesn't matter what the value of the `Color` column is)